# GDB show R/W Permissions in specific memory address

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, permissions, gdb

I have a simulation in Matlab Simulink which uses an SO library file with my algo code. I want to know the read/write permissions of a specific memory address using GDB. For example I care about knowing the permissions on the memory of this variable:

```
(gdb) p &CalValid
$3 = (const WORD *) 0x91f6005c <CalValid>
```

If I use `(gdb) maintenance info sections` it shows only the memory space of the matlab process and no the loaded library.

Exec file:

```
`/appl/matlab2010a32/bin/glnx86/MATLAB', file type elf32-i386.
0x8048134->0x8048147 at 0x00000134: .interp ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
0x8048148->0x8048168 at 0x00000148: .note.ABI-tag ALLOC LOAD READONLY DATA HAS_CONTENTS
...
0x0000->0x00c4 at 0x00001fa0: .comment READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
0x0000->0x0010 at 0x00002064: .gnu_debuglink READONLY HAS_CONTENTS
```

The reason I need this is because even though the variable is const I have `mprotect()` elsewhere in the code changing memory permissions of cont variables.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no built-in command for this. However, if you grab the process ID (`info proc`), in Linux, you can read the `/proc/PID/maps` pseudo-file, which reflects the actual memory mappings in the process being debugged; find the address range that contains the symbol, and the third field on that line has the protection mode (`rwxsp`, where `s` refers to shared, and `p` private or copy on write). So, if `show configuration` in GDB shows `--with-python`, then you can write a Python extension to GDB to provide this new command for you.